# MOXy: Throw WebApplicationException with different entity type than return value of handler

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

I have a JAX-RS service using Jersey and MOXy. I have a handler that returns the JSON or XML (depending on the `Accept:` header) representation of a type `Memo`, but if the item is not found, it should return a 404 error with the JSON or XML representation of a different type `MemoError`.

With `Accept: application/json` it's working correctly in the first case (returning `Memo`), but not in the second (throwing WebApplicationException with `MemoError` entity).

If I change my handler to return a `MemoError`, the second case does work (but the first one doesn't, obviously).

It also works correctly in both cases with `Accept: application/xml` (using the default JAXB implementation), so I think the issue is with MOXy.

the handler:

```
@Path("{id}")
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Memo getMemo(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    Memo memo = memoService.getMemo(id);
    if (memo == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response
                .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(new MemoError(4, "Not found")).build());
    }
    return memo;
}
```

MemoError:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
public class MemoError {
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public MemoError() {
    }

    public MemoError(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Dec 26, 2013 1:05:55 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder process
SEVERE: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
Dec 26, 2013 1:05:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet JAX-RS Servlet threw exception
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class my.package.MemoError was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.descriptorNotFoundInProject(XMLMarshalException.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.getSession(Context.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:787)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext$XMLContextState.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context.getSession(Context.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLContext.getSession(XMLContext.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:808)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:243)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:574)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `@XmlSeeAlso({MemoError.class})` on the `Memo` class.

Comment: This worked, but I'm curious why it is not required for XML. Any ideas?